# Shorten string if possible and assign to variable

Tags: c#

I have a string `MTopic` that sometimes is more than 50 characters, sometimes is less. So I have added this type of code:

```
if (MTopic.Length >= 50)
{
  Console.WriteLine(MTopic.Substring(0, 50));
  var MTopicShort = MTopic.Substring(0, 50);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine(MTopic);
  var MTopicShort = MTopic;
}
```

I want to use `MTopicShort` later in my code:

```
FilesAction(MCountry, MTopicShort, MDeadline);
```

However Visual Studio is giving me an error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0103  The name 'MTopicShort' does not exist in the current
>   context

I know this is very basic of C#, but I can't find an answer.

Comment: You declare the variable `MTopicShort` inside the body of the `if` statement (and the `else` statement), so the variable is only in scope until the closing `}`. Declare the variable outside of the `if` statement instead: `string MTopicShort; if (...) { ... MTopicShort = ... }`

Comment: declare `string MTopicShort = string.Empty;` before `if`

Comment: @canton7 you mean `string MTopicShort = string.Empty; if (MTopic.Length >= 50) { var MTopicShort = MTopic.Substring(0, 50); }` ?

Comment: @hatman No. I meant `string MTopicShort; if (...) MTopicShort = ... ; } else { MTopicShort = MTopic; }`. But you could also write it `MTopicShort = MTopic; if (...) { MTopicShort = ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're declaring `MTopicShort` within the scope of the `if` and `else` blocks so once you exit those blocks `MTopicShort` has gone out of scope and no longer exists.

Since you're always printing out the short version just declare and initialize `MTopicShort` in one go:

```
var MTopicShort = (MTopic.Length >= 50 ? MTopic.SubString(0, 50) : MTopic);
Console.WriteLine(MTopicShort);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared two `MTopicShort` variables, one only visible in the scope of the `if` block, the other only visible in the scope of the `else` block. The method call `FilesAction(MCountry, MTopicShort, MDeadline)` is in neither of those scopes, so it doesn't work.

One way is to declare the variable outside of the `if` (but not initialise it):

```
string MTopicShort;
if (MTopic.Length >= 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MTopic.Substring(0, 50));
    MTopicShort = MTopic.Substring(0, 50);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(MTopic);
    MTopicShort = MTopic;
}
```

Another way is to always do a `Substring`, but with a length of `Math.Min(50, MTopic.Length)`:

```
var MTopicShort = MTopic.Substring(0, Math.Min(50, MTopic.Length));
```